# How to send zero fee bitcoin transaction

Tags: transaction-fees, sending

Please does anyone know how I can send zero fee bitchin transactions? I know if might not confirm, I just wanna know if there are any wallets or sites or softwares that I can use to accomplish this.

Comment: As RedGrittyBrick noted below, a transaction is only considered reliable after it is confirmed. The first confirmation happens when a transaction gets included in a block. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve by sending a transaction that doesn't get confirmed. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core and a number of libraries that facilitate building transactions will allow you to create a zero fee transaction. The problem is that most nodes on the network will not relay transactions with a fee rate below the `minRelayTxFee` (1 satoshi/virtualbyte). Additionally, most miners don't include transactions below the `minRelayTxFee` in their blocks.

Comment: I don't care if it never confirms, I just want it to appear on the blockchain. I would to know the simplest way to do this as I'm not experienced in writing codes and can't download the whole blockchain on bitcoin core.. Maybe like a wallet or site that will help me achieve this.

Comment: @sissy, not being confirmed is the same as not being in the blockchain

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason wallet force fees is to prevent spam, if they allow customer to send zero fees transaction that have almost no chance of being accepted by miner, their node will be banned (my guess).

In fact you should be careful if you find a wallet that allow you to do zero transaction fees, since they have no incentive to do that it could be a scam trying to steal your private keys.

The solution is simply to make your own node so you can play around and test with zero fee transaction, you can start there:
https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node